# Symbolic Links in Windows with PHP project using Netbeans 7

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit, symlink

I'm working on a PHP project and using Netbeans 7.0.1 and the last PHPUnit.

The project has two folders each one with its own bootstrap.

Let's say folders are project1 and Common, then project1 uses a SymbLink to access Common and in Mac world that works, but now I'm working on windows and from project1 unit tests, Common files are not found.

I tried to add Common folder as Global Path in Project1, but it still doesn't find Common files.

Is there any place where I can configure Netbeans to work?
Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I've used this tool, and it might depend upon which version of Windows you're running, but you might also look into a tool called Junction Link Magic.  It does symlinks on Windows, or some version thereof.

That being said, relying on symbolic links in the manner you're describing seems non-portable at best.  My stronger recommendation would be to fix your build script (ant/maven/whatever) so that it works everywhere without relying on symlinks in the first place.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because it was kind of the same I did. I created with a program I downloaded from the web (Symlink Creator.exe) and replace the Symlink created in Mac with the one created in Windows (both pointing to the same folder). That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to add the Common folder to your [include path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php). Otherwise, you can always just copy and paste the actual folder (not recommended).

Comment: As I said in the original post, I already did that...but the files are not found either.

Comment: That only covers NetBeans. You need to add Common to Project1's include path in `bootstrap.php`. This tells PHPUnit how to find the files.

Comment: My bad, sorry.  Did you figure it out now?

Comment: Yes, chekc my Comment on the previous answer